# Get cursor starting index before text changed in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, selection, textwatcher

This may seem like a simple question but I don't understand why it happens .I want to get the start and end indexes of a selection in my edittext before user changes the text so In my TextWatcher I did as follows:-

```
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                    selectionStart = edittext.getSelectionStart();
                    selectionEnd = edittext.getSelectionEnd();


            }
```

However both selectionStart and selectionEnd return the ending index of the selection.For example I select a word "**hello**" both return **5**.I tried inserting them in a handler to get the selection before any keyboard input to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem its a bit ugly but optimally solves the problem .The problem was that before textchanged the text selection was already gone so I had to use a handler to wait when text is selected and a span watcher to set the selections immediately after like so:-

```
final SpanWatcher watcher = new SpanWatcher() {
@Override
public void onSpanAdded(final Spannable text, final Object what,final int start, final int end) {

final Handler handler = new Handler();//handler to get selection after 
certain time
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

if(noteview.hasSelection()) {

higlightdetect=1;//integer to detect that text was selected

selectionStart = noteview.getSelectionStart();
selectionEnd = noteview.getSelectionEnd();

                    }else
higlightdetect=0;
                }
            }, 600);//after 600ms seemed to be the optimal time after selection occurs
        }
}

@Override
public void onSpanRemoved(final Spannable text, final Object what,
                                  final int start, final int end) {
            // Nothing here.
        }

@Override
public void onSpanChanged(final Spannable text, final Object 
what,final int ostart, final int oend, final int nstart, final int nend) 
{
//The same

final Handler handler = new Handler();//handler to get selection after 
certain time
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

if(noteview.hasSelection()) {

higlightdetect=1;//integer to detect that text was selected

selectionStart = noteview.getSelectionStart();
selectionEnd = noteview.getSelectionEnd();

                    }else
higlightdetect=0;
                }
            }, 600);//after 600ms seemed to be the optimal time after selection occurs
        }
};


edittext.getText().setSpan(watcher, 0, edittext.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//set spanwatcher to edittext
```

Of course this works only when text is selected cant use it for regular typing since it will auto update instantly after text is changed so in the text watcher I added this code:-

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
count, int after) {



if(higlightdetect==0){//condition to get cursor position without selection

selectionStart = noteview.getSelectionStart();
selectionEnd=selectionStart;
}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
count) {

        }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

Toast.makeText(getthenote.this, String.valueOf(selectionStart), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(getthenote.this, String.valueOf(selectionEnd), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

higlightdetect=0 //resetting higlightdetect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the `start` parameter in the `beforeTextChanged` method?